# check with no content at runtime without assertions

Tags: eiffel

As far as I understood in Eiffel, the following code without assertions fails if the statement returns `False`

```
check
    i_m_alive: i.alive
then
    do_nothing
end
```

Maybe I'm badly using it but sometimes I'd like to check it without doing anything else.

- What is the exact behavior of this statement with and without assertions?
- Should I use a `raise` with an `if` statement?
- I sometimes try to add an else statement to the `check ... then` but its not implemented I'm sure for a reason, probably because there is no alternative as an exception is raised in case the statement returns `True`

Specially on EWF (Eiffel Web Framework) the only way I see to report an error and treat it is either to write into logs or sending the details to the referrer with some details which are sometimes not adequate to send to the user. Sending an email to the administrator is also a possiblity... I'm a bit lost, but know that the raise and Exception mecanisms is not the way Eiffel recommends to treat errors.

I'll dig further into the [available documentation](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/solutions/Exception_Mechanism) about that but think as me the TL;DR will be happy to have a more concise answer or more points of view about that.

Comment: I would suggest moving the last question about `rescue` and stack trace to another post because it is not directly related to the original question, and violates the rule to ask one question rather than several ones.

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov Thx, actually I found some more infos you wrote about that and think I'm mixing things too much to do the right thing on the right case. I think my software has to use more error controls as advised into your post of following link than on check, retry, raises. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956743/examples-of-error-handling-in-eiffel/26983044

Comment: I'll study more in deep my code and will come with more questions once its clearer on my mind, bad habits of using exceptions and having an error which doesn't seem to be fixed still on eiffel compiler which doesn't make me able to compile with assertions a final executable for test & prod made me confuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of assertions as of statements that specify current state of the program in your code. For example:

- here the variable `x` is equal to `5`;
- here all elements of the list are attached to existing objects;
- here two structures have the following relationship, etc.

The assertions just describe the behavior of the program (i.e. they are declarative). They do not define the behavior (i.e. they are not imperative).

Assertions could come in different forms: class invariants, pre- and postconditions, loop variants, etc. But all of them are declarations of the program state when execution reaches the corresponding point at run-time. Removing such declarations does not change the behavior. Whether assertions are checked or not is controlled by compiler and run-time options. If the program is correct, i.e. no single assertion is ever violated, such removal does not affect the final result (except, maybe, performance). Moreover, some tools can verify the assertions at compile time, so that run-time checks are not needed at all. In other words, assertions are used to specify program behavior whereas other code is used to implement the behavior.

However, if the program is incorrect, an exception is triggered. It tells the programmer that there is an error and that it should be fixed.

The same applies to the construct `check ... then ... end`. It says that the specified conditions are always met (if the implementation is correct). If the condition is violated, there is a bug in the program. That's why there is no `else` part: this construct does not control program execution, it just checks that the execution goes as expected.

If the compiler would be smart enough, if could check the condition at compile time and either report an error, or remove the condition altogether (if it is provably never violated). However, the current technology is not still there. As a result, the code to check the condition (let's call it "assumption") is generated and checked at run-time. In particular, it ensures that the code in `then` part can safely rely on the checked assumption. Such checks become critical in [void-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/void-safety/info) code when the compiler cannot correctly infer attachment status of the expression that is known (to you as a developer) as always attached. Unlike other assertions, this one cannot be turned off (in fact, some preconditions cannot be turned off in SCOOP as well - they are part of the semantics).

If you want to use exceptions as a way to control program behavior, assertions is not the right tool. As you mention, explicit calls to `raise` exceptions should be used instead.

To summarize:

- assertions describe program behavior, they are not intended to affect the behavior;
- exceptions that control program behavior should be raised explicitly (and this should be avoided);
- `check ... then ... end` is mandatory and is checked regardless of compiler and run-time settings;
- there is no `else` part because assertions do not control program behavior.